# PHP search query not working

Tags: php

so basically I'm trying to get the search to take the title and then ignore titles in the search but take the keywords associated with that title and display other items with the same keywords if that makes sense.

This is my code but it only searches for what you put in. I don't know how to make it do what I want.

```
<?php
        $k = $_GET['lookfor'];
        $terms = explode(" ",$k);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE ";
        foreach ($terms as $each) {
            $i++;
            if ($i == 1)
                $query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
            else    
                $query .= "OR keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
        }   
    // connect
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password");
    mysql_select_db("icarus");

    $query = mysql_query($query);
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if ($numrows > 0) {

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
            $id = $row['id'];
            $title = $row['title'];
            $description = $row['description'];
            $keywords = $row['keywords'];
            $link = $row['link'];

            echo "<li type='1'><h3><a href='$link'>$title</a></h3>
            <p>$description</p><br /><br /></li>";
        }
    }
    else
        echo "<p>No results found for '<b>$k</b>'. Icarus is still in the early development stage, this can happen.</p>";

    // disconnect
    mysql_close();
    ?>      </div>
```

Sample data:

```
ID:          INT
Title :      Linkin Park - Hands Held High
Description: About the song
Keywords:    rap rock anti war political
Link:        youtube link to song
```

Comment: what do you mean by `take the title and then ignore titles in the search but take the keywords associated`

Comment: Please add table definition and some sample data

Comment: I mean do not display similar titles to the search term but only display titles that have similar keywords

Comment: Apart from sample data, also give an example of a search you do on **that** sample data, the outcome you get, and what outcome you want to have.

Comment: If I search for say Linkin Park - Hands Held High I get only that song but what I'm looking for is it to list other songs that have the sam keywords like political, rock, rap, anti war.

Comment: Stop using `mysql_` functions, they have been deprecated for a long time now. Use `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead. Also your code is vulnerable for SQL injection. Use prepared statements.

Comment: I repeat myself: please provide (1) data -- with more than 1 record, (2) the search you launch on it, (3) the output you get, (4) the output you wanted to get. Please put this in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think i've manged to decypher what you're requesting.

Have a read through this, stemming search terms will get the keywords out of what was typed in.

http://www.codediesel.com/php/porter-stemming-in-search/